# e2e testing in angularjs for page navigation

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I am writing e2e tests for my web app and stuck at the very beginning. I would appreciate any help to kick start my testing experience.

I am completely new to angularjs. So please bear with me.

I want to write a test that will check if we are on the landing page of the app. I am using jasmine and karma.

here is my config file
        // Karma configuration

```
    module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '../',
    // frameworks to use
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'source/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js',
            'test/lib/angular-mocks.js',
            'test/scripts/**/*.js',
            'test/unit/**/*.js',
            'test/e2e/**/*.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [

        ],


         // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


       // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN ||   config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
       logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // Start the browser, currently available:
        browsers: ['Chrome'],


        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        captureTimeout: 60000,


        // Continuous Integration mode
       // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: false
      });
    };
```

my mainscenario.js file.

```
        describe('appName', function() {

            beforeEach(function() {
                browser().navigateTo('../../source/views/home/landing.html');
            });


            it('should automatically redirect to landing page when location hash/fragment is empty', function() {
                expect(browser().location().url()).toBe("/landing");
            });
```

Well i cant post the screen shot of the error as it needs 10 reputation. But here is a description.

```
    AngularJS: Scenario Test Runner1 Errors0 Failures0 Passed
    describe: appName
    165ms should automatically redirect to landing page when location hash/fragment is empty
    118ms   browser navigate to '../../source/views/home/landing.html'
    8ms $location.url()
    http://localhost:8000/test/e2e/mainscenario.js:9:16

    TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'injector'
        at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/test/lib/angular-scenario.js:27230:30)
        ...........blah blah
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are going for E2E tests in angular, use protractor. It will simplify your life.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that your webserver is running and that karma is running too.
Take a look at this article, it helped me:
http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/06/a-small-angularjs-jasmine-test-executed.html

Also, my `karma-e2e.conf.js` looks like this:

```
    module.exports = function( config ) {
        config.set({
            basePath: '../',
            plugins: ['karma-ng-scenario', 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-chrome-launcher','karma-html2js-preprocessor'],
            frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],
```

Note that I use `'ng-scenario'` in frameworks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like incorrect order of loading packages.

Try loading all libraries first then load `app.js` and then your `controllers`, `dir`s, etc.